# How to render InnerBlocks in Gutenberg version 4 using php $content

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

This was working fine with Gutenberg 3:

```
function render_block($attrs, $content){
    ob_start();
        echo $content;
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

But with the recent update of gutenberg, `$content` is always null, even when passing it from save callback as:

```
    save: function(props) {
        return el( InnerBlocks.Content );
    },
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a bug in the Gutenberg itself and was fixed in WP 5.1.1

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**block.js**

```
(function (blocks, editor, components, i18n, element) {

    var el = element.createElement;

    blocks.registerBlockType('block-category/block-name', {

        ...

        edit: function(props) {

            el(editor.InnerBlocks, {
                allowedBlocks: ['core/heading'],
                template: [['core/heading', {'placeholder':'Placeholder text'}]],
            })

        },

        save: function(props) {

            return el(editor.InnerBlocks.Content);

        }

    });

})(
  window.wp.blocks,
  window.wp.editor,
  window.wp.components,
  window.wp.i18n,
  window.wp.element
);
```

**block.php**

```
add_action('init', function() {

    wp_register_script(
        'block_script',
        plugins_url('block.js', __FILE__),
        array('wp-blocks', 'wp-components', 'wp-element', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-editor'),
        filemtime(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'block.js'),
        true
    );

    'editor_script' => 'block_script',

    register_block_type('block-category/block-name', array(

        'render_callback' => function($attributes, $content) {

            return $content;

        }

    ));

});
```

Comment: Please ensure you explain what changes you have made and what was wrong with the original code. Posting just blocks of code makes it difficult for future visitors to this question to work out what the resolution was. Thank you!